# Mesh deforming severely when trying to use armature

Tags: animation

I have been having a issue where when i try to rig something with armature, it severely deforms the mesh. A image is better of explaining it than I am.[image]

Comment: Looks like a classic case of bad vertex weights. That is, some vertices are more / less “weighted” to be influenced by a particular bone than they should be. There are many tutorials and other questions on the subject. Search “vertex weight painting.”

Comment: It also looks like overlapping geometry to me... if you haven't retopologized yet, do that, get a good edge flow with no inner faces